# Magento 2 Categories and subcategories doesn't show up on sidebar

Tags: magento2, link

I'm using Magento2 with Venustheme - Yume , and I created some product categories , with some subcategories , that also have other subcategories , But on the sidebar they doesn't show up, the strange thing is that they show up on another category that only has subcategories , without any eventually subcategories to the subcategories..